# Value from Context Not Rerendering

Tags: reactjs, render, react-context

I'm using two variables from a context, but they don't consistently render based on the way I use them in the return.

```
// given a dictionary and key passed in from context
const {myDict, KEYTOMATCH} = useContext(...);
```

This works as I expect it to:

```
{Object.keys(myDict).map((key, index) => {
    if (key === KEYTOMATCH) {
      return <SomethingToRender />
    } else {
      return <></>;
    }
  })}
```

Why do the below not work?

```
{myDict[KEYTOMATCH] && (
    <SomethingToRender />
)}

{Object.keys(myDict)
    .filter((e) => e === KEYTOMATCH)
    .map((e) => (
    <SomethingToRender />
))}

{Object.keys(myDict).includes(KEYTOMATCH) && (
    <SomethingToRender />
)}

{Object.keys(myDict).includes(KEYTOMATCH) ? (
    <SomethingToRender />
) : (
    <></>
)}
```

Thank you!